# sequelize subquery as field

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to get such query to be generated by sequlized:

```sql
SELECT 
    "Customers"."id", 
    (SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders"
     WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customers"."id") AS "totalAmount",
    "Customer"."lastName" AS "Customer.lastName",
    "Customer"."firstName" AS "Customer.firstName" 
FROM "Customers" AS "Customer";
```

I'm trying to avoid `GROUP BY` clause, as I have a lot of fields to select and I don't want to group by all them (I think it's not efficient, isn't it?)

I've tried several ways for making it happen with sequelize, include `{include: ...}` and `{attributes: [[...]]}`, but without any luck.

Any ideas? or maybe should I use one big `GROUP BY` clause and let all the "regular" fields to be grouped-by?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your best option is:

```ts
    return Customer.findAll({
        attributes: Object.keys(Customer.attributes).concat([
            [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders" WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customer"."id")'), 'totalAmount']
        ])
    });
```

---

This looks like an extension to issue [#1869](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1869):

> Querying on the through model/join table is not possible currently unfortuneatly.

Your question is also tangentially related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640627/node-js-multiple-sequelize-raw-sql-query-sub-queries), where the question there was sort of a "for each user query associated table".

Looking at the [test code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/6a0912ad82915fd7bf20bd71ad7707abd473a137/test/integration/include/findAll.test.js) for the `include` clause I don't see any group options, which is an absence of evidence for this feature.

Solutions:

Of course, you could just pass the query "raw":

```ts
    return sequelize.query(
        'SELECT *, (SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders" WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customer"."id") AS "totalAmount" FROM "Customers" AS "Customer";',
        Customer,
        {raw: false}
    );
```

That will give you want you want, and wrapped into `Customer` instances.

Alternatively, you could add an instance method that returns another promise:

```ts
instanceMethods: {
    getOrderSummary: function () {
        return Order.findAll({
            where: {
                CustomerId: this.id
            },
            attributes: [
                [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('amount')), 'sum'],
                'CustomerId'],
            group: ['CustomerId']
        });
    }
}
```

The instance method version isn't very clean, but it works ok and may be more appropriate depending on your situation.

The best solution that I've found is to use a SQL literal in the `attribute` field of a query. The only downside is that it seems to wipe the slate clean on selecting the other attributes, and a '*' doesn't cut it. So, you need to do the workaround with `Object.keys()`.

```ts
    return Customer.findAll({
        attributes: Object.keys(Customer.attributes).concat([
            [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders" WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customer"."id")'), 'totalAmount']
        ])
    });
```

Still, it works a charm and you could use that for some more interesting nested SELECTs. And that `findAll` gives us the correct:

```ts
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "firstName", "lastName", "createdAt", "updatedAt", (SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders" WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customer"."id") AS "totalAmount" FROM "Customers" AS "Customer";
{ id: 1,
  firstName: 'Test',
  lastName: 'Testerson',
  createdAt: Wed Feb 04 2015 08:05:42 GMT-0500 (EST),
  updatedAt: Wed Feb 04 2015 08:05:42 GMT-0500 (EST),
  totalAmount: 15 }
{ id: 2,
  firstName: 'Invisible',
  lastName: 'Hand',
  createdAt: Wed Feb 04 2015 08:05:42 GMT-0500 (EST),
  updatedAt: Wed Feb 04 2015 08:05:42 GMT-0500 (EST),
  totalAmount: 99 }
```

BTW, I also tried doing it backwards and using the GROUP BY on the `Order` model to select into the `Customer` model, but that didn't work:

```ts
    // Doesn't work
    return Order.findAll({
        attributes: [
            [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'orderCount'],
            'CustomerId'
        ],
        include: [
            {model: Customer, attributes: ['id']}
        ],
        group: ['CustomerId']
    });
```

Comment: cool. I have to adapt this to my use case, but it seems to workaround my current problem. 10x.

Comment: Good call on the `Object.keys(Customer.attributes).concat()` I could not figure out why the other attributes were not showing up despite `*`.

Comment: For those reading this much later, @srlm has created a nice blog post clearly explaining this including an elaboration on the instance method approach. http://srlm.io/2015/02/04/sequelize-subqueries/

Comment: Note that in current Sequelize, the `attributes` field on the Model has been renamed to `rawAttributes` for some unfathomable reason. So you have to do `Customer.rawAttributes`.

Answer (score 11):

In Sequelize 4, you can add extra attributes using the `attributes.include` syntax http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

```ts
return Customer.findAll({
    attributes: {
        include: [
           [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM("Orders"."amount") FROM "Orders" 
            WHERE "Orders"."CustomerId" = "Customer"."id")'), 'totalAmount']
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Its getting added in the query but how to access it ?

Comment: You should be able to access it as just an attribute on the returned instance, e.g. if you have a Customer from the above query (which returns an array of Customers) , `Customer.totalAmount`, but if that's not working then try `Customer.get('totalAmount')` or `Customer.dataValues('totalAmount')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy.